# Is it possible to get the modulo with decimals

Tags: scheme, modulo

When i compile (modulo 10.5 5) in scheme. It produces an error. `In procedure modulo: Wrong type argument in position 2: 10.5.`

How can i check this and the value if the number 10.5 is divisible by 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical function `modulo` is only defined on integers. It does not make sense to apply it to floating-point numbers.

**EDIT:** As discussed in the comments below, here is a predicate returning either `#t` or `#f` that determines if a divisor *d* evenly divides a number *n* with no remainder:

```
(define (divides? n d)
  (let ((q (floor (/ n d))))
    (zero? (- n (* q d)))))
```

Note that this may fail due to floating-point approximation.

Comment: "The mathematical function modulo is only defined on integers. It does not make sense to apply it to floating-point numbers." Not true. Many languages have a function like `fmod` that does modulo on floating-point numbers. In some languages, like Java, Python, Ruby, the `%` operator operates on floating-point numbers directly.

Comment: @Newacct: Please tell me what is the answer to `(modulo 10.5 5)`.

Comment: The Scheme function `modulo` doesn't work on non-integers; there can be ones that work on non-integers, like `flmod` in R6RS, and it would return 0.5.

Comment: @Newacct: I agree that 0.5 is the remainder when dividing 10.5 by 5, and since the remainder is non-zero we can say that 5 does not divide 10.5. But it is not the modulo, as defined in mathematics. Conflating the words "remainder" and "modulo" is not helpful. I've edited my response to provide code that answers the original poster's question.

Comment: Why is the C standard library function `fmod` called what it is if it's not related to the word "modulo"?

Answer (score 0):

`modulo` doesn't work with decimals because it only accepts integers. As discussed above, you can define another procedure to see if two numbers are divisible by each other. Otherwise, the computer doesn't know how to accept non-integer numbers for `modulo`.