# Why 5.24% 1 = 0.2400000000000002 in java?

Tags: java

If `5.24/1` is `5.24` then `1*5.24 = 5.24`, so why is `5.24%1 = 0.24`? It should be 0, right? Because `1*5.24=5.24`? which leads to a zero in remainder?

Does mod only take the int part of a decimal to divide and produce a remainder?

Comment: Nice numbers in decimal are rarely nice numbers in binary and you see a rounding error.

Comment: But we still love them, most of the time.

Comment: I don't get your logic here. `/` is not `%` - those are two totally different operations.

Comment: If I understand your reasoning correctly, would you also say that `3 % 2 == 0` since `3 / 2` is `1.5`, which leaves no remainder?

Comment: @Brian `3/2 == 1` in Java, just saying :)

Comment: @Amongalen I'm aware. My comment is intended to highlight the error in the OP's reasoning.

Comment: the modulo operator (%) should only be applied to integers, so round before.

Comment: Here is a discussion about that topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221470/is-it-possible-to-get-the-modulo-with-decimals

Comment: Here is a description of how module works on floating points in java. It is not the same as on integers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947044/how-do-i-use-modulus-for-float-double

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `%` operator for floating point numbers is so that the modulus is multiplied by an integer.

5.24 % 1 = 0.24 because

5.24 = **5***1 + **0.24**

There is a separate issue with rounding error and what numbers can be represented exactly in binary floating point, which makes the result slightly different from 0.24.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. So in short the mod operator in programming doesn't work with the fractional part of a decimal number, correct ?

Comment: It does if you use a modulus with a fractional part. `3.625 % 1.25` gives `1.125` because `3.625 = 2*1.25 + 1.125`

Comment: Yes, only when both part are decimal/float or either one ?

Comment: No: `3 % 1.25 = 0.5`